# Бот в сообщениях отправляет одну ссылку вместо нескольких

Tags: python, парсер, telegram-bot, telebot

Проблема в том что, когда бот отправляет сообщение с ссылкой, под всеми сообщениями 1 единственная ссылка, при том что во время парсинга я доставал каждую из них. Правда я не знаю как исправить это(

```
def callback_inline(call):
    sxodim_link = ''
    
    if call.data == 'today':
        for i in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'info'):
            for link in soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'img'):
                sxodim_link = link.get('href')
            keyboardurl = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
            event_url = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Перейти на сайт ->', url=sxodim_link, callback_data='sxodimlink')
            keyboardurl.add(event_url)
            #for link in soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'img'):
             #   print(link.get('href'))
            if i.find('div', class_ = 'str bold'):
                bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, i.find('a', class_ = 'title').text.strip() + '\n' + ' ' + i.find('div', class_ = 'str bold').text.strip() + '\n', reply_markup = keyboardurl)
            else:
                bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, i.find('a', class_ = 'title').text.strip() + '\n', reply_markup = keyboardurl)
```

Comment: Не думаю, что это проблема именно бота. Скорее всего алгоритма парсинга. Выведите себе в консоль то, что вы через бота отправляете, наверняка заметите ошибку. Проверьте, что `i.find` возвращает именно от текущего тега в `i`

Comment: Странно вы работаете с `sxodim_link = link.get('href')`, там действительно нужно всегда в цикле перебирать и всегда брать последний элемент?

Comment: Если предоставите пример html, что парсите и какой ожидаемый результат, то это поможет в решении проблемы

Comment: @gil9red, в том то и дело что я никак не могу реализовать эту логику, не могу додуматься никак

Comment: А ссылки в `sxodim_link` должны отличаться, верно? И они как-то связаны с тем что вы из `'div', class_ = 'info'` вытаскиваете?

Comment: @gil9red, да они связаны, т.к. Эти ссылки находятся в классе info, с тегом "а" где класс "img"

Comment: Ну, я так и подумал... Вам нужно в цикле перебирать общий для тех элементов теги и внутри цикла искать `info` и `img`, тогда `Перейти на сайт` будет иметь разные ссылки. Как писал выше если с этим проблемы, то в вопросе добавьте кусок html что нужно попарсить или ссылку с указанием что пытаетесь вытащить

Comment: @gil9red, с парсингом и получением ссылок нет, все правильно и по порядку. Проблема в отправке ссылок. Он почему то отправляет только последную ссылку из самого листа ссылок.

Comment: @gil9red, я нашел ошибку, она в keyboardurl, следующая ссылка просто заменяет предыдущую, но я не знаю как ее исправить

Comment: Не думаю, что ошибка там, посмотрите мой второй комментарий. А еще третий, если сами не можете справиться с этим

Comment: @gil9red, я проверял это, с парсингом ссылок все ОК, как я сказал там ссылки просто заменяются следующей. Я это уже проверял

Answer (score 0):

Это потому что Ваш `sxodim_link` сохраняет только последнюю ссылку! Если Вы хотите что бы ссылок было много переведите `sxodim_link` в список -

```
sxodim_link = []
for i in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'info'):
    for link in soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'img'):
        new_link = link.get('href')
        sxodim_link.append(new_link)
```

Если хотите навести красоту при отправке сообщений переведите список в строку и очистите -

```
sxodim_link = str(sxodim_link).replace('[', '')
sxodim_link = sxodim_link.replace(']', '')
sxodim_link = sxodim_link.replace("'", '')
bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, sxodim_link, reply_markup = keyboardurl)
```

Comment: Спасибо, я это учту, задача немного упростилась, НО, он все равно возвращяет мне последнуюю ссылку листа, мне кажется проблема в

keyboardurl = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
event_url = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Перейти на сайт ->', url=sxodim_link, callback_data='sxodimlink')
keyboardurl.add(event_url)

И я никак не могу понять как можно это исправить

Comment: Вы хотите отправить несколько ссылок одним сообщением?

Comment: https://sxodim.com/almaty/event/tantsevalnye-sessii-house-dance-share-session https://sxodim.com/almaty/event/virtualnyj-den-otkrytyh-dverej-v-ie-university https://sxodim.com/almaty/event/onlajn-kurs-likbez-po-ekonomike https://sxodim.com/almaty/event/onlajn-kurs-20-kutjurje-izmenivshih-mir https://sxodim.com/almaty/event/onlajn-kurs-glavnye-sobytija-v-mirovoj-istorii https://sxodim.com/almaty/event/vebinar-derevo-ponjatij-testirovanija

Comment: Но как Вы хотите что бы при нажатии на кнопку открывалось 5 ссылок? Нужно сделать 5 кнопок. Или сделать ссылки в тексте а не кнопках

Comment: У меня Бот отправляет текстовое сообщение через форик. И мне нужно чтобы под каждым сообщением была определенная ссылка